# Image with text aside

Tags: graphics, jpeg

So far I have not needed to insert jpg images in my LaTex files, but now I want to write a text that will include some pictures.

I would like a format where the picture doesn't take the full width of the page but be rather set to the right or the left and the remaining space on its side filled with text.

I have tried to use the figure environment from the graphicx package together with a minipage environment, but failed.

What would be the best way to proceed? Is it safe (or even possible) to change from a one column format to a two columns format in the middle of a page?

Comment: Perhaps `wrapfigure` environment is what you want. Cf. the basic explanation at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Inserting_Images, section "Wrapping text around figures"

Answer (score 2):

Consider this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \section{First section}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
        %\vspace{-2cm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{wrapfigure}
        \lipsum[2]
        
    \begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.3\textwidth}
        %\vspace{-2cm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[3][1-9]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This looks nice. Thanks!